# Removing external CSS files with hook?

Tags: 7, theming

My theme is adding the following CSS below. How can I remove it? I know that with Drupal 6 you can do `stylesheets[all][] =` in the .info file but what about Drupal 7? Can `hook_css_alter()` be used on an external file?

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to remove your external css

```
function hook_css_alter(&$css) {
  // Remove defaults.css file.
  unset($css['path of you external css']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `hook_css_alter` can be used with external CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Use [function hook_css_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7) you can unset css

```
function hook_css_alter(&$css) {
  // Remove defaults.css file.
  unset($css[drupal_get_path('module', 'system') . '/defaults.css']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function [hook_css_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7). This hook function will alter CSS files before they are output on the page.

```
//This hook function will unset css.
function hook_css_alter(&$css) {
    // Remove defaults.css file.
    unset($css['CSS FILE PATH']);
}
```

In additionally, you want to remove core css then follow below code:

```
function hook_css_alter(&$css) {
    $exclude = array(
        'misc/vertical-tabs.css' => FALSE
    );
    $css = array_diff_key($css, $exclude);
}
```

just add `$exclude` to your info to remove a CSS file. This is simple way to remove css file.

Let me know if there is any doubt/query from this.